Why is the UV mapping different in the render?
The render view in the viewport looks like this:

But when rendering, the texture mapping looks different.

The giant square is fractured into pieces. The pieces are separate meshes which are all unwrapped onto the same UV map. So the faces of all the pieces are scattered across a single UV map. But in the render mode, the UV map is wrapped to each piece separately. Can someone please tell me what's wrong here?
Here are the UV map and the emission texture where the red is applied to the faces that are not facing the camera.


Hello maybe you have several UV maps? You need to check in the Data > UV Maps panel, or please share your file?

@moonboots There is only one UV map which is wrapped differently in the render. I've attached the UV maps for reference.

Could you please share your file?
